# XML DML for SQL Server 2008

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, dml

I have an xml column `ExportTemplate` in a table that holds an xsl template that I need to modify.

When I use the the query below, the server notifies that 1 row is affected but when I check the actual row, the change has NOT been persisted. Any ideas? Thank you.

```
update Exports 
set ExportTemplate.modify('
declare namespace xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform";
declare namespace xslt="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform";
insert <Fuel><xslt:value-of select="Fuel"/></Fuel>
after (/xsl:stylesheet/xslt:template[3]/Vehicle/Condition)[1]')
where ExportCode ='AutoTrade';
```

Comment: my bad, it has NOT been persisted ;)

Comment: OK, can you **show us** the XML content so that we can understand why your `.modify()` call might fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very good answer from MSDN forum. Thank you.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlxml/thread/2b9a46ee-663b-4d25-bef1-7d4f0c650839